# $(':radio, :checkbox', this) why 2 arg in a $ selector? in jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, selector

```
  $(':radio, :checkbox', this).wrap('<div style="margin: 1px"/>');
  $(this).buttonset();
  $('label:first', this).removeClass('ui-corner-left').addClass('ui-corner-top');
  $('label:last', this).removeClass('ui-corner-right').addClass('ui-corner-bottom');
```

as above, I can understand why there are 2 arg in a $?
I has googled but still cannot find a related discuss

Comment: That is called as a context. Restricting the selector to that particular scope. http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this selector:

```
$(':radio, :checkbox', this)
```

`this` is the wrapper which contains `radio and checkbox`.

consider this example:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   if(!$(':checkbox, :radio', this).prop('checked')){
      alert('please select checkbox and radio.');
   }
});
```

so in the above example `$(':checkbox, :radio', this)` this selector you can see it is in the context of `$('form')` so here `this` is actually `form` and you are trying to select the specific child of it.

This line is actually you can write like this too:

```
$(this).find(':checkbox, :radio')
```